# CSS FlipCard in Safari (3d transforms)

Tags: css, safari, transform

A simple FlipCard app. The app works fine in Chrome, but not in Safari.
In Safari, upon clicking, the text on the back of the card is seen, it flickers, and then disappears.

The idea for the code came from this link: [w3schools/howto/css-flip-card](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_flip_card.asp)

HTML:

```
<div class='flip-card'>
<div class='flip-card-inner'>
<div class='flip-card-front'><p>1</p></div> 
<div class='flip-card-back'><p>2</p></div> 
</div> 
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.flip-card {
perspective:1000px;
-webkit-perspective:1000px}

.flip-card-inner {
position:relative; 
transition:transform 0.8s;
-webkit-transition:-webkit-transform 0.8s;
transform-style:preserve-3d;
-webkit-transform-style:preserve-3d}

.flip-card-front, .flip-card-back {
position:absolute;
backface-visibility:hidden;
-webkit-backface-visibility:hidden;}

.flip-card-back  {
transform:rotateY(180deg);
-webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);}
```

JS:

```
$('#flash-card-game').on('click',function(){FlipToBack()});

function FlipToBack(){
$('#flash-card-game').css("transform","rotateY(180deg)");
$('#flash-card-game').css("-webkit-transform","rotateY(180deg)");
setTimeout(FlipToFront,1000);}

function FlipToFront(){
$('#flash-card-game').css("transform","rotateY(0deg)");
$('#flash-card-game').css("-webkit-transform","rotateY(0deg)");}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try this please

```js
$('#flash-card-game').on('click', function() {
  FlipToBack()
});

function FlipToFront() {
  $('#flash-card-game').removeClass("flip-to-back");
  $('#flash-card-game').addClass("flip-to-front");
}

function FlipToBack() {
  $('#flash-card-game').addClass("flip-to-back");
  setTimeout(FlipToFront, 1000);
}
```

```css
Write the folowing CSS

.flip-to-front {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
  transform: rotateY(0deg);
}

.flip-to-back {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

Comment: I tried to figure out what is the problem. I have tried on iPad2 and safari but nothing happened and the card isn't moving at all.

Answer (score 1):

For others, here is the solution I found after a few days of trial and error.
My question did not provide the real cause of the error. I had a background image in the parent container:

```
.flip-card-inner {background:url('image.png') no-repeat top}
```

This caused the text on the back of the card to flicker and disappear after flipping in Safari on the iPad.

I moved the background image from the parent container to the front and the back elements.

```
.flip-card-front, .flip-card-back {background:url('image.png') no-repeat top}
```

It then worked no problem in Safari on the iPad.